# Backup WSL folder to USB without logging in as administrator

Tags: windows, backup, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 7-zip, windows-backup

I am trying to backup my complete WSL data to a USB drive; however, I'm running into a 7zip administrative rights problem when I do it simplistically (creating the zip with the same windows user that I run WSL under).

#### Questions

- How should I create a WSL backup archive as the same user I run WSL under?
- robocopy is an option if I can find the way to specify the source WSL folder(s)
- If this can't be done with 7zip or robocopy, is there a more appropriate (free) Windows backup option for this situation?

*Create the 7zip archive*
[image: create 7zip archive]

*7zip parameters - Save zip file to the USB:*
[image: 7zip Archive parameters]

**7zip errors: Access is denied.**
[image: 7zip admin errors]

Comment: Why can’t you use the [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#import-and-export-a-distribution) command to export it? 7zip isn’t going to have permissions to the file. I assume you can’t run 7zip as an Administrator.

Comment: `wsl --export Debian D:\Debian.export` works, please post as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: I submitted that answer 3 years ago.